# Please help me with this Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Calculate the integral (complex):

> $$\oint_{D(0,1)}\overline ze^z \mathrm dz$$

While $D(0,1)$ is the unit circle.

Comment: On the unit circle, do you know a way to express $\overline{z}$ differently?

Comment: Yes, of course it could be either x-iy (in cartesian coordinates) or e^{-it} (in polar coordinates, as t represents the Argument of z)

Comment: Can you express it in terms of $z$?

Comment: I think the answer will be z¯= (|z|^2)/z (if z is non-zero)

Comment: On the unit circle, what is $\lvert z\rvert^2$?

Comment: Well, it is 1 but I still get the integrand (e^z)/z which I'm unexperienced with

Comment: Does an integrand of the form $\dfrac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$ not ring a bell?

Comment: All right! I understand it all now! thanks a lot Daniel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting the hints from the comments in an answer:

On the unit circle, we have $\overline{z} = \dfrac{1}{z}$. Hence the integral can also be written

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{e^z}{z}\,dz,$$

which by the Cauchy integral formula evaluates to

$$2\pi i e^{0} = 2\pi i.$$

Comment: Nice, short and accurate. +1, though by the basic nature of the question perhaps the OP hasn't yet covered the CIF.

Comment: [This comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585774/please-help-me-with-this-integral/585810#comment1236978_585774) makes me believe (s)he knows it.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that before. Delete on its way.. .